# Changing elements of a list of lists

Tags: python

I need to add 0.05 to elements of coords array. But nothing happens.
Can you advise me where is the mistake? (I thought this would be easy but no)

```
coords = [[0.1,0.1,0.1],
          [0.2,0.2,0.2],
          [0.3,0.3,0.3]]

for i in coords:
    for j in i:
        j = j+0.05
   
print(coords)
```

Comment: Do you need to add it to all the lists in ```coords```

Comment: yes I should add all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current way will not store the results, as you did not provide a list to hold the results. I can show you two more straightforward examples:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

for number in a:
    number = number + 1
    
# check results
# nothing happens
print(a)
```

But if you do:

```
# you will get results

b = [number + 1 for number in a]
print(b)
```

The only difference is that you need to provide a list to hold the data.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't actually modify the elements in the list by iterating over j. You could try a double list comprehension like this:

```
coords[:] = [j+0.05 for i in coords for j in i]
```

This has the advantage of editing the original object without creating a new instance of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
coords = [[0.1,0.1,0.1],
      [0.2,0.2,0.2],
      [0.3,0.3,0.3]]

for i in range(len(coords)):
    for j in range(len(coords[i])):
        coords[i][j] += .05
    

print(coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lst comprehension

```
coords = [[0.1,0.1,0.1],
          [0.2,0.2,0.2],
          [0.3,0.3,0.3]]

newCoords = [[num+0.05 for num in lst] for lst in coords ]
print(newCoords)
```